# ctrl+c doesn't wait for child process (background process) to finish with trap

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, sigint, bash-trap

I have a script which registers a SIGINT trap and starts a ffmpeg background process that records part of the screen. The SIGINT trap sends a SIGINT signal to the background ffmpeg process to get it to gracefully stop and finish the recording.

When this script is run in a terminal, and terminated from a separate terminal with `kill -INT [SCRIPT_PID]`, the ffmpeg background process terminates gracefully and outputs confirmation in terminal 1.

When the script is run in a terminal and stopped with `ctrl+c` the background process just dies instantly. (even if ctrl+c should just send a SIGINT signal)

Why does ctrl+c behave differently than killing the script with `kill -INT` in this case?
How can i make sure the ffmpeg background process ends gracefully when ending the script with ctrl+c?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

exit_script() {
    kill -INT $ffmpeg_pid
    wait $ffmpeg_pid
    printf "\n\nffmpeg should say 'exiting normally, received signal 2' before this message is printed!\n\n"
}

trap exit_script SIGINT 

ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 500x500 -i :0.0+0,0 ~/video_`date +%s`.webm &
ffmpeg_pid=$!

wait
```

edit: it seems like ffmpeg receives 2 int signals in the case of `ctrl+c`, but i don't know why